# BxSlider - responsive videos not working properly

Tags: html, video, slider, bxslider

I am trying to create a slider with 4 videos that I have in webm, ogv, and mp format (each). I used BxSlider - here is the sample: http://www.dinzign.com/test/

When you look at it on the laptop, it totally works. you can see a preview of each video, the arrows click through to the next and previous screens, etc.

When i pull this up on mobile however,things are all over the place. The arrows dont work, I dont see a preview of the video. I have tried several sliders and its driving me crazy - I don't understand whats the issue here.

I created an html page for each video (with  tags) and then I am pulling these into each of the

tags for the slider.... PLEASE HELP!!!!

Here is the HTML:

```
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/plugins/jquery.fitvids.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.bxslider.js"></script>
  <link href="jquery.bxslider.css" rel="stylesheet" />

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
    video: true,
    useCSS: false,
    touchEnabled:true,
    preventDefaultSwipeY:true
    });
    });
</script>

</head>
<body>

<ul class="bxslider">
    <li><iframe src="videos/video1.html" width="100%" height="240px" frameborder="0"></iframe></li>

    <li><iframe src="videos/video2.html" width="100%" height="240px" frameborder="0"></iframe></li>

    <li><iframe src="videos/video3.html" width="100%" height="240px" frameborder="0"></iframe></li>

    <li><iframe src="videos/video4.html" width="100%" height="240px" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</li>

</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Move the Loading of the CSS file to the top, before you load the JS --- any difference?

Comment: Did not help. I ended up using another slider. Any other content in the iframes works, but if i embed a html5 video, the arrows become un-clickable.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `$(document).ready(function()`

OR

Read about it in [FAQ](http://bxslider.com/faqs) section of bxslider.

> Are you calling .bxSlider() inside of a $(document).ready() call? For more info on the .ready() call, [click here](http://www.learningjquery.com/2006/09/introducing-document-ready/).